# Is animated api of react-native is supported in react-native-web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-web

I making mobile web app and need to add animation. So I am thinking of using react-native animated api but I am not sure if it support react-native-web 
Please suggest if you have any alternatives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The animated API is available within react-native-web. You can use exactly the same API's as you know from react-native itself. One thing to take in notice is that all the Animations are running on the main JS thread which can lead to slower user in/output.

Using css animations is also supported which you can fall back to if the performance of your animation are causing problems.